# monitering cpu usage per core

Tags: macos, command-line

I need to monitor cpu usage per core or at least total % used.

I can't use `top` because I need to sandbox the app. As the sandboxed apps cant run `setuid` commands.

So, is there any method to obtain the information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A similiar question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855440/how-to-get-cpu-utilization-in-in-terminal-mac) on Stack Overflow. You can use ps to get the total usage percentage like this:

```
ps -A -o %cpu | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s "%"}'
```

For a detailed explanation of what this does, see the original link.

Comment: Is there a way to get `user`  `system`  `idle` ? Also usage per cpu like `CPU 1: 14%  CPU 2: 17%`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this without top or htop on OSX.